# How to find the reflection matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, geometry, differential-geometry

$V$ is an m dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{C}^n$ , n>m with an orthonormal basis {$q_1$,..,$q_m$}.

How to find the reflector $P\in \mathbb{C}^{nxn}$  that reflects about $V$. $P$ must depend on only $q_1,..,q_m$

Could you please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix $Q = \displaystyle\sum_{k = 1}^{m}q_kq_k^T$ represents the orthogonal projection onto $V$.

So, for any vector $x \in \mathbb{C}^n$, we have $x_{\parallel} = Qx$ is the part of $x$ that lies in $V$ and $x_{\perp} = x-Qx = (I-Q)x$ is the part of $x$ that is orthogonal to $V$.

To perform a reflection, we need to flip the orthogonal part and leave the parallel part unchanged.

Specfically, $x = x_{\parallel}+x_{\perp}$ reflected about $V$ should give us $x_{\parallel}-x_{\perp}$. Do you see how to do this?

Comment: I see why it is $x_{||} -x_{\perp}$.

Comment: Try to compute $x_{\parallel}-x_{\perp}$ in terms of $x$ and $Q$ using the equations for $x_{\parallel}$ and $x_{\perp}$. If you can get $x_{\parallel}-x_{\perp} = [\text{matrix}]x$, then $P = \text{matrix}$.

Comment: is the matrix P= $2Q-I$

Comment: That's what I got. To double check your answer, try that formula for a simple example, such as $\mathbb{R}^2$ where the subspace $V$ is the $x$-axis (so $q_1 = (1,0)^T$). Does the matrix $2q_1q_1^T-I$ give you a matrix which reflects vectors about the $x$-axis?